# Copy directories using BackgroundWorker

Tags: c#, .net

I am writing an app to copy the contents of a directory to a removable drive. I'd like to know if there is a better way of structuring this.

The UI layout is a `TreeView` for selecting the source directory, a `CheckedListBox` which lists the removable drives, and a copy button.

Here is the code I have for when a user clicks the start copy button. This method actually doesn't copy anything, it really is just checking to make sure the user selected a folder and destination drive properly.  Is there a better way to do this, with exceptions?

```
private void StartCopy()
{
    // Set UI properties and other vars
    PictureBox1.Visible = false;
    TreeNode aNode = dirsTreeView.SelectedNode;

    // Check to make sure user has selected a source folder, and set sourceDir variable.  if not, exit method
    if (aNode != null)
        sourceDir = (string)aNode.Tag;
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please select a valid source folder.", "USB Batch Copy", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        return;
    }

    // Check if source drive is ready, exists.  If any of these are true, exit method
    DriveInfo dInfo = new DriveInfo(sourceDir.Substring(0, 2));
    if (!dInfo.IsReady || !Directory.Exists(dInfo.Name))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Source folder does not exist, or source drive is not ready.  Please try again.", "USB Batch Copy", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        dirsTreeView.Nodes.Clear();
        PopulateTreeView(dirsTreeView);
        return;
    }

    // Check if source folder is empty.  Exit if true
    if (IsDirectoryEmpty(sourceDir))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Source folder is empty; cannot copy an empty folder.  Please try again.", "USB Batch Copy", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        return;
    }

    // If no drives are checked in CheckedListBox, exit method 
    if (lstDrives.CheckedItems.Count == 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please select at least one destination drive.", "USB Batch Copy", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        return;
    }

    // Add checked items in CheckedListBox to list object
    PopulateListOfDrives(lstDrives, listDrivesToCopy);

    // Check to make sure source drive and destination drive are not the same, exit if true
    // Check to make sure user did not remove drive after refresh, but before copy
    foreach (var destDir in listDrivesToCopy)
    {
        if (sourceDir.Substring(0, 1) == destDir.Substring(0, 1))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Source drive and destination drive cannot be the same.  Please try again.", "USB Batch Copy", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            return;
        }
        if (!Directory.Exists(destDir))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Target destination drive does not exist.  Please try again.");
            RefreshDrives(lstDrives, dictRemovableDrives);
            return;
        }
    }

    // Disable UI controls   
    if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["autoRefresh"] == "0") { btnRefreshDrives.Enabled = false; }
    btnSelectAll.Enabled = false;
    btnSelectNone.Enabled = false;
    btnStartCopy.Enabled = false;
    lstDrives.Enabled = false;
    dirsTreeView.Enabled = false;
    lblStatus.Text = "Copying...";
    lblStatus.ForeColor = Color.Black;

    // Begin the copy in BackgroundWorker
    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

`BackgroundWorker`:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    int totalItems = listDrivesToCopy.Count();

    // Start copy execution
    try
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < listDrivesToCopy.Count(); i++)
        {
            ExecuteSecure(() => lblStatus.Text = string.Format("Copying drive {0} of {1}..", (i + 1), totalItems));  // Update status label securely
            string destDir = listDrivesToCopy[i];
            FileSystem.CopyDirectory(sourceDir, destDir, UIOption.AllDialogs, UICancelOption.ThrowException);
        }
    }
    catch (ArgumentException)  // Catch user removal of drive during copy 
    {
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException)  // Catch user cancelling copy
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
    catch { }
}
```

`BackgroundworkerCompleted`:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{                        
    if (e.Cancelled)
    {   
        // The user cancelled the operation.                
        lblStatus.ForeColor = Color.Black;
        lblStatus.Text = "Ready";
        MessageBox.Show("Copying operation has been cancelled.", "USB Batch Copy", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
    }            
    else if (e.Error != null)
    {
        // There was an error during the operation.
        lblStatus.ForeColor = Color.Black;
        lblStatus.Text = "Ready";
        RefreshDrives(lstDrives, dictRemovableDrives);
        MessageBox.Show("An error has occured: " + e.Error.Message, "USB Batch Copy", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
    }
    else
    {
        // The operation completed normally.
        PictureBox1.Visible = true;
        lblStatus.ForeColor = Color.Green;
        if (lstDrives.CheckedItems.Count == 1)
            lblStatus.Text = "Success! Copied to 1 drive.";
        else
            lblStatus.Text = string.Format("Success! Copied to {0} drives.", listDrivesToCopy.Count());                
    }

    // Enable UI controls            
    if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["autoRefresh"] == "0") { btnRefreshDrives.Enabled = true; }
    btnStartCopy.Enabled = true;
    btnSelectAll.Enabled = true;
    btnSelectNone.Enabled = true;
    btnStartCopy.Enabled = true;
    lstDrives.Enabled = true;
    dirsTreeView.Enabled = true;

    SetCheckState(lstDrives, false);
}
```

Can I model this differently?

Comment: Don't use BackgroundWorker, that's an antiquated construct that has been made obsolete by Tasks.

Comment: If you are populating the full list of drives before starting the background worker is in not really a producer consumer type model.  Just kick off a task as suggested in the prior comment.